# Do we apply this substitution to calculate the integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I want to calculate the integral $\int \frac{1+\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt[3]{x+1}}\, dx$.

We substitute $u=x+1 \Rightarrow x=u-1:=\phi (u)$. Then  $\phi '(u)=1$.

So, we get
\begin{equation*}\int \frac{1+\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt[3]{x+1}}\, dx=\int \frac{1+\sqrt{\phi (u)+1}}{1-\sqrt[3]{\phi (u)+1}}\cdot \phi'(u)\, du=\int \frac{1+\sqrt{u}}{1-\sqrt[3]{u}}\, du\end{equation*}

Do we substitute now $w=1-\sqrt[3]{u}\Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{u}=1-w \Rightarrow u=(1-w)^3:=\phi (w)$ ?

Then we get $\phi '(w)=3(1-w)^2\cdot (1-w)'=-3(1-w)^2$.

And so
\begin{equation*}\int \frac{1+\sqrt{u}}{1-\sqrt[3]{u}}\, du=\int \frac{1+\sqrt{\phi (w)}}{1-\sqrt[3]{\phi (w)}}\cdot \phi '(w)\, dw=\int \frac{1+\sqrt{(1-w)^3}}{1-\sqrt[3]{(1-w)^3}}\cdot (-3(1-w)^2)\, dw\end{equation*}

Is this correct so far? Or do we not apply this substition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

substitute $$x+1=t^6$$ or $$x=t^6-1$$ then we get
$$dx=6t^5dt$$ and out integral will be
$$\int\frac{1+t^3}{1-t^2}\cdot 6t^5dt$$
note that $$\frac{1+t^3}{1-t^2}=\frac{1-t+t^2}{t-1}$$
and write yout Integrand in the form
$$\frac{t^5(t^2-t+1)}{t-1}={t}^{6}+{t}^{4}+{t}^{3}+{t}^{2}+t+1+ \left( t-1 \right) ^{-1}$$
since the degree of the polynomial in the numerator is greater than the polymial in the denominator you must do Polynom division

Comment: I suppose you mean $x=t^6-1$.

Comment: just a typo, thank you Bernard

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps it would be clearer to the novice saying you set $x+1=t^6$.

Comment: thank you again for this hint, i have added this!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! But how can we calculate the integral $\int\frac{1-t+t^2}{t-1}\cdot 6t^5dt$ ?

Comment: i have added a line Mary, solve this your Problem?

Comment: I understand!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: i wish you a nice day, Mary!